# problems in c# process navigate in cmd using readline

Tags: c#, cmd, process

I'm having a problem using process.StandardInput.WriteLine (command).
**I am trying to create a program that simulates the CMD in C #**, so that it is possible to enter several commands and navigate the folders using the "cd" without closing the process (I don't want to start another process because it started with the default location). The first command works fine, but when I want to enter one more command, it hangs. I think it's because I'm closing the StandardInput(). Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            string command = Console.ReadLine();
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

        }
```

[Photo of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRaiN.png)

Comment: how are you entering the commands?

Comment: by  Console.ReadLine(); in C# console

Comment: You are correct.  The Close and Exit should not be in the while loop.

Comment: Well, when I delete the 2 lines I have no output and freezes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to find a good solution for this problem, because if you try to leave out:

```
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

You will observe that ReadToEnd() will never return a string, i guess this has to do with cmd.StandardOutput.BaseStream's unablility to provide a stream position.

***So my workaround is this:***

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();
string END = "E-N-D";
while (true)
{
    string command = Console.ReadLine();
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(END);
    cmd.StandardInput.Flush();

    string oldLine = "";
    string newLine = "";
    bool endOfOutput = false;
    bool oldLineIsEmpty = true;
    do
    {
        newLine = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        if (newLine.Contains(END))
        {
            endOfOutput = true;
        }
        else if (!oldLineIsEmpty)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(oldLine); 
        }
        oldLine = newLine;
        oldLineIsEmpty = false;
    } while(!endOfOutput);
}
cmd.WaitForExit();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
```

After every command, a hopefully **unique** END code is sent, which is not a valid command, but a good way for spotting the end of the output stream, because it appears there, too.

OldLine is used as a buffer to prevent a newline, after the first command, from being written to Console.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. I spent almost 2 days breaking my head looking for a solution. Also works with the command "cd" :D

Comment: I'm happy for you :)